# How to elimimate rotten meat smell from underneath the fridge

Tags: smell

Inadvertently left semi open the door of the fridge that we keep in the garage. When i realized about 16 hours later, food was no longer frozen and meat liquid spilled out when i fully opened the door. I cleaned the floor but 48 hours later the freezer and the garage smelled horribly rotten. The smell seems to be coming from underneath the freezer. We moved the freezer and cleaned the floor, but still smells really bad. The inside does not have bad smell.
Any suggestions about how to get rid of the odor? I use bleach for the freezer legs but it did not help. Not sure where to clean

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate - https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/15001/6973

Comment: Hi Olga, **Welcome** to StackExchange Lifehacks. You might want to visit [Help] and [Tour] to find out more about the site and how to get the most from it. For your trouble, you'll get a bronze "rep" badge for your ID.

Comment: Cleaned it with what?

Comment: Dont forget to rinse and clean the plastic container that sits over the compressor at the back, this catches some liquid from inside.

Answer (score 1):

Get a small container of **Ozium**™ spray.

I had to remove a freezer full of frozen chicken parts that had been unplugged after an ugly eviction proceeding.

The freezer had been without power for more than a couple of weeks and the odour was overwhelming and difficult to describe.

I used **Ozium**™ spray to minimize the odour while I emptied the freezer and then the apartment of the freezer which I did not try to clean. I don't think I could have done the job without it.

It was recommended to me by morgue technicians as an aid to working in difficult situations.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I use my hand held steamer  that has a powerful pressure  and a wire scrubbing tip to blast away dirt and oder. I would  soak the area with  a heavy Vinegar spray first and after 30 mins, hit the area with the high pressure, high heat steam.